# Reading multiple excel files with no col.names, adding column with file names

Tags: r, file, purrr

I have multiple excel files with similar format, but col.names vary because of format ("Nº Expedición" v. "NÂº Expediciï¿½").

Thus, i want to read them omitting column names, also adding a column with file name.

I have solved both separately, but I cannot find how to have them at the same time.
The col.names = F part is not working, but I don't know how to introduce it in the script.

```
df <- purrr::map_dfr(list.files(path = ., 
                                pattern = "80_*", full.names = TRUE, recursive = T),
               ~read_excel(.x), col.names = F %>% mutate(file = sub(".xls", "", basename(.x))))
```

Answer (score 0):

... Only had to put col_names = F, and inside read_excel function:

```
~read_excel(.x, col_names = F)
```